# SQL banking race condition

Tags: mysql, postgresql, race-condition

I am building a banking system in NodeJS and an SQL database. The two main functionalities I need are deposit and withdraw. I want to make sure that there are no race conditions.

Ex: User has 100$ balance and withdraws 100$ twice quickly and ends up with -100$.

Can the following query have race conditions?

`update account set balance = balance - x where balance > x`

If this does not solve the problem:

If I use PostgreSQL, will a check constraint on my balance column suffice to eliminate all race conditions?

If I use MySQL, what are my options?

I am curious on what are the different ways to achieve this in both PostgreSQL and MySQL

Comment: Why can't you use `transaction`?

Comment: How does transaction help? @DarshanMehta

Comment: Explained it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can do the following:

- Set autocommit to false inside `withdraw()` function, i.e. start a new transaction.
- Use `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` to read the record
- Perform checks on value (i.e. whether amount is sufficient enough to perform the operation)
- `UPDATE` the value
- End the transaction

Now, when user tries to withdraw twice quickly, one of the call will start the transaction and issue `SELECT.. FOR UPDATE` call, that will block the other thread from reading the data. It will be only unblocked once first thread will finishes, i.e. it will prevent `race condition`.

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html) MySQL's documentation about it.

Comment: does the following command: 
update account set balance = balance - x where balance > x 
have a race condition though?

Comment: No, it doesn't. However, you need to `SELECT` the balance before updating it to prevent a user from having negative balance and that does have a race condition as `SELECT` doesn't lock the record.

Comment: Why do you need to select anything 'first'?

Comment: To validate the value before updating it